# Issue Running Migration in Laravel: Forcing Use of 'customer_id' Column Instead of Searching for 'id_customer'

Tags: laravel, migration, pivot-table

I'm encountering an issue while trying to execute a migration in Laravel and I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve it. I would like to add a new boolean column called is_visible to my customer_user table. However, when I attempt to run the migration, Laravel is looking for a non-existent column named id_customer instead of using the existing customer_id column.

Here's the code snippet from my migration:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddIsVisibleToCustomerUserTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('customer_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('is_visible')->default(true);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('customer_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('is_visible');
        });
    }
}
```

I understand that Laravel has a default convention to search for the id_customer column, but I wish to stick with the existing customer_id column. How can I force Laravel to use the customer_id column when adding the new column?

I've already attempted running the php artisan migrate --force command, but the error persists. I've also tried investigating the previous migration, which involved renaming columns, to see if that's causing conflicts, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

I greatly appreciate any help or guidance you can provide.

Comment: your code does not include `id_customer` column tho, the migration you show has nothing to do with that column

Comment: "_has a default convention to search for the id_customer column_" I always thought Laravel's convention was to use `customer_id` (in your case). Can you please post the complete error message you get?

Comment: @brombeer you are correct. I found some code with `id_customer` and this is the wrong way, indeed. I'm going to change all to `customer_id` which is the default Laravel way.